# ¿Por qué el evento KeyPress no válida el Enter?

Tags: vb.net, eventos, visual-studio-2017

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código el cual no me valida la tecla Enter en absoluto, simplemente no entra el evento solo con esa tecla, con cualquier otra tecla si entra el evento pero con el Enter simplemente no pasa nada de nada

```
    Private Sub TXTBusqueda_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TXTBusqueda.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        MsgBox("Enter")
    End If
End Sub
```

pero tengo otro formulario con este codigo donde si entra el evento cuando presiono la tecla Enter y cualquier otra tecla tambien

```
    Private Sub CorreoTxt_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles CorreoTxt.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        ValidarCorreo(CorreoTxt.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Quería aclarar una cosa, el TextBox que solo no me detecta la tecla Enter esta dentro de un control creado por mi, es decir el procedimiento que hice fue hacer clic en el menú "Proyecto" después en "Agregar control de usuario" y dentro del panel agregue un TextBox, no se si afecte en algo pero como dije todas las demás teclas si las detecta dentro del evento KeyPress, el otro TextBox que si funciona normal esta dentro de un formulario común.

Comment: Se necesitaría un [mcve] para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Probablemente (no tengo el dato asegurado en mi cabeza ahora) se esté procesando el "enter" antes de que te llegue el evento. Yo intentaría usar el evento `KeyDown` o `PreviewKeyDown` en lugar de `KeyPress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamento haber tardado en responder, encontré la respuesta hace un par de días y lo que pasa es que tengo un TextBox con autocomplete source y eso afectaba el keypress solo con la tecla Enter, y como Pikoh sugirió, la respuesta era usar KeyDown aun que no me agrada mucho usar ese evento pero soluciono el problema, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Sé que han pasado 4 años desde que formulaste esta pregunta, pero entre tanto ensayo y error con la base de conocimiento que me distes pude solucionar también mi error.

Estaba tratando de que al hacer enter en un solo form sobre un solo textbox, se me abriera un cuadro de diálogo y lo logre con la siguiente instrucción.

Ojo con esto soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y asumí visual basic para iniciar porque me parece muy sencillo de usar y rápido de comprender.

```
 Private Sub Actualizar_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Actualizar.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        MsgBox("Mensaje en Pantalla", vbYesNo, Title:="Actualizar Factor en Saint")
        If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            ConsultasSQL1.ActualizarFactor(FACTORVENTANA:=Actualizar.Value)
            Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Este es mi pequeño aporte rápido y sencillo para aquellos que se topen con el mismo desafío que yo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!! pero no entiendo como soluciona esto el problema que tenia OP, que venia por otro lado...

Comment: ¡Solo te di un ejemplo de como solucionar mi problema que era similar al tuyo :), ya lo que coloques en el if dependerá de ti!.

Comment: Yo no hice la pregunta.. solo revise tu respuesta, y te vuelvo a preguntar, porque tu codigo soluciona el problema que OP expuso en su pregunta? mira por favor [answer]... Trato de que tu respuesta tenga sentido en base a la pregunta...